# Greetings! I want to read json file locally without Internet through simple HTML and JS, after running the code it throws an error here is my code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

```
    fetch("./my_json_file.json")
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            mydata = data;
            console.log("this is " + mydata)
            console.log("now " + mydata)

            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
            var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).PolarArea(mydata);
        });
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SHL7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS6FU.png)

https://www.tutorialstonight.com/read-json-file-in-javascript

I tried these above three methods I get what I do not needed.

Comment: it does not work with file protocoll, use a local webserver software to use http protocoll

Comment: Yes dear but am building this for a local and offline app.

running with live server (Extension of VS code) it works but running directly it do not work.

Comment: Hey, a local webserver works offline ;) no internet required

Comment: I recommend you to further research what your options are, it realy depends on your definition of `app` there is plenty to find on the web

Comment: you can't read a local file using javascript in a browser. that would be a security breach and nobody would use that browser.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API

Comment: thank you sir, Now I got it and I will complete My app and then after creating built  and exe file if it works then fine otherwise I will search for any other quick method.
Thank you all for Helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommended: use a web server. Web browsers do not allow access to local files for security reasons. You can use the Live Server extension for VS Code and it will be local and offline (no internet connection needed).

NOT recommended: you might be able to launch your web browser with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` command-line flag. But that will make you vulnerable to security risks! Web browsers might not support that command-line flag anymore.